# Saving/loading application data in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a Qt program that needs to save and load some files to persist some data between runs of the program.  How do I locate the appropriate OS-specific directory in which to store these files?  Does Qt provide an API for this?

(The SDL library has for example [SDL_GetBasePath](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetBasePath) and [SDL_GetPrefPath](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetPrefPath).  Does Qt offer a similar API?)

Comment: I suspect I'm after https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html

Comment: you probably interested in `QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation`

Comment: @AndrewTomazos Why didn't you use it, then? This is an extremely poorly researched question for a 56.1k user.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: I discovered QStandardPaths after posting the question.  Rather than delete it, I thought I would leave it up in case other people find it useful.  I think you're being pretty casual with your downvote.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos Please hover your mouse over the downvote button for more "casual" information on how the site works. Cheers

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: I stand behind what I said.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos, and I stand behind what I've said. `QStandardPaths` is not the way to store appliaction data. `QSettings` is. However, the accepted answer does not reflect that.

Comment: @scopchanov: Comment added to your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation` is probably what you're looking for. From the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html):

> Returns a directory location where persistent application data can be stored. This is an application-specific directory.

Answer (score 1):

You might indeed use `QStandardPaths` to store application specific data. However, the intended class for such purposes is [`QSettings`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html):

> The QSettings class provides persistent platform-independent application settings.

**Note:** I personally prefer the ini format `QSettings::IniFormat`, user scope `QSettings::UserScope` and organization as folder, e.g.:

```
QApplication::setApplicationName("MyApplication");
QApplication::setOrganizationName("MyOrganization");
QSettings settings(QSettings::IniFormat, QSettings::UserScope, QApplication::organizationName(), QApplication::applicationName());
```

On Windows 10 the above code creates a file `MyApplication.ini` under:

```
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\MyOrganization
```

An additional benefit to the automatic storing of the settings in the correct location for the particular OS is the automatic parsing of the data file.

Comment: I appreciate the pointing out of QSettings, and this answer is welcome and should remain - but to be clear I spoke of multiple files to be stored, and asked for a directory to store them.  Not all application data is appropriate for ini format and QSettings.  For example, large binary files.